# Combine English language and alternative locale

Tags: language-support, locale

I have setup my Ubuntu machine to use the English (US) language. I have setup regional formats to use a Dutch format.

The problem is that weekdays and months names are defined by the regional format, not the language setting.

Can I configure the locale in such a way that everything is in English, but use Dutch the locale for anything else?

For example:

```
English: Thu 08 June 2019 10:15:59 PM CET
Dutch: do 08 juni 2018 22:25:59 CET
Wanted: Do 08 June 2018 22:25:59 CET
```

Comment: There is only `LC_TIME` I believe that will impact date/time formatting and you want a case mixing basically two locales for a time format. Besides defining a new locale where you set it to do what you want, I am not convinced you can reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot arbitrarily select which part of a string in an arbitrary program uses which locale you have installed.

You will need to create a custom locale and translate strings to fit your desired translation and formatting, in a non-standard way as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `en_DK.UTF-8` locale. Open `~/.profile` for editing and add this line:

```
export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
```

This takes effect at next login.