Date format in Firefox / Ubuntu
In web pages rendered in Firefox 125 on Ubuntu 24.04, I'd like dates to have format yyyy-mm-dd. So  should use that format for display. Now I see mm/dd/yyyy.
In Firefox Language is English (UK).
In Ubuntu Language is English (UK).
In Ubuntu, for Format I put Denmark because that has the right date format, but it doesn't help.

Does this answer your needs? -> https://askubuntu.com/q/1449351/289138

Unfortunately not. That post suggests LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8 which I already had (I set it from UI). But Firefox's  still shows format dd/mm/yyyy not yyyy-mm-dd.
